# Google Calendar API - determine how much free time a person has between a start time and end time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone, google-calendar-api, timezone-offset

I'm trying to build a dashboard indicating how much free time a set of employees has based on their calendar so we know who has time to work on different projects.  I'm using the Google Calendar APIs and can't seem to get everything I need to build this information.  I could really use a sanity check.  I'm hoping that I'm missing something obvious.

What I'm specifically trying to do is to determine how much free time there is in a user's calendar between 8a and 5p in their local time zone.  Even more specifically, only calendar events that they've accepted should be counted as "busy" since there are always a number of optional events on their calendar.  I've tried accomplishing this in a couple of ways, but keep coming back to the same issue, timezone.

I can get the current timezone of the user's calendar by calling https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/get with the appropriate calendar ID.  This returns a timezone in IANA format (America/Denver for example).  However, all of the other Google APIs I would use to retrieve information (Freebusy, or events list) require you to provide a start time and end time in RFC3339 format with a mandatory offset (2022-10-28T08:00:00-06:00 for example).  So even if I know that I want to retrieve information from October 28, 2022 from 8am to 5pm, I don't have an offset to work with.

At this point it seems like I need:

1. To be able to convert the IANA string into the current timezone offset (accounting for DST)
2. To be able to retrieve the current calendar's timezone offset, rather than an IANA string
3. To be able to call the Google Calendar APIs without a specific offset, but provide an IANA timezone
4. Someone to tell me I'm going about this all wrong.

Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can achieve #1 with a library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/).  There's a clear example in [the Luxon docs here](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/zones?id=creating-datetimes-in-a-zone). The other approaches are invalid, because a time zones and offsets are not the same thing.  A time zone *has* an offset (which may be different at different points in time).